# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) - while splitting whole number and decimal

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert a float to its binary representation. I don't get why when I try to split the whole number and the decimal part, I get this error

`ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`

Here is the code

```
import decimal
from ctypes import *
def float_bin(number, places = 32): 
    **whole, dec = str(number).split(".")** 
    whole = int(float(whole)) 
    dec = int (float(dec)) 

    res = bin(whole).lstrip("0b") + "."

    for x in range(places): 
        whole, dec = str((decimal_converter(dec)) * 2).split(".") ////error here
        dec = int(dec) 
        res += whole 
    return res 

def decimal_converter(num):  
    while num > 1: 
        num /= 10
    return num 


a = float(float_bin(0.0000567))   
print ('%32.f', a)
number = cast(pointer(c_float(a)), POINTER(c_int32)).contents.value
bitpos = 0
while number != 0:
  bitpos = bitpos + 1             # increment the bit position
  number = number >> 1 # shift the whole thing to the right once
  if(number >= 1) :
     break

  print ('%3.f', bitpos)
```

Comment: In order to debug problems like that you could add some `print` statements between the lines. Then you can easily see that `dec` before the `for x in range(places):` is zero, hence no decimal dot to split on.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your problem is with the representation of your number in form 5.67e-05. When you convert this to string your code breaks

Instead you can use the following function

```
import decimal
from ctypes import *


def float_bin(number, places = 32): 
    whole, dec = str(decimal.Decimal(value=str(float(number)))).split(".")
    whole = int(float(whole)) 
    dec = int (float(dec)) 

    res = bin(whole).lstrip("0b") + "."

    for x in range(places): 
        whole, dec = str((decimal_converter(dec)) * 2).split(".")
        dec = int(dec) 
        res += whole 
    return res 

def decimal_converter(num):  
    while num > 1: 
        num /= 10
    return num
```

and the output will be

```
float_bin(0.0000567)
Out[35]: '.10011011101100110011001100110011'
```

For correct function output, you might need this

```
import decimal
```

from ctypes import *

```
def float_bin(number): 
    whole, dec = str(decimal.Decimal(value=str(number))).split(".")
    whole = int(float(whole)) 
    dec = int (float(dec)) 
    return  bin(whole).lstrip("0b") + "." + bin(dec).lstrip("0b")

def decimal_converter(num):  
    while num > 1: 
        num /= 10
    return num 

float_bin(0.0000567)
Out[52]: '.1000110111'
```

Comment: I checked with this website https://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/ and your code doesn't give me the correct value

Comment: I identified and corrected the error you were getting, not the function output

Answer (score 0):

You defined "dec" as an integer in line 6, then you perform integer (floor) division on it in decimal_converter, which also returns an integer, which then has no decimal point to split on.